# Can't access on Teams after change domain password

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-teams, credentials-manager

I've changed my domain password, so after that, my Microsoft Teams has stoppped to work.

- I've tried to go on Credential manager about remove all credentials
  about Teams (as adviced by Microsoft support page) but nothing.
- I've tried to clean the Microsoft Teams cache in this folder:

  > C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Teams\Cache

But nothing.

When I try to access on `Microsoft Teams` I've got this message:

> Can you please sign in again? Sorry for any inconvenience. Login Now

But when I click on "Login Now" starts a blu circle but the loop is infinite.

I don't know how to resolve this issue

My O.S. is `Windows 7 Professional with S.P.1` on 64 bit PC

Comment: I've just had this issue, and Teams finally started after I edited manually the password of my Windows Credentials concerning `Microsoft_OC1:uri=myemail@mydomain:specific:CER:1` and `Microsoft_OC1:uri=myemail@mydomain:specific:OCS:1` (no idea what they mean, but it's the ones that I think intuitively they could be related to Teams, and their "Modified" date was a few months ago althouth I had changed my password two days ago).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my organisation, we have gotten around this by *intentionally* putting in an incorrect password to force the login to fail, which breaks the loop.  Then, you can choose the option to log in by specifying an email address, and try again - it should work.

Comment: Hi, I don't konw, because beofre your response, I've uninstalled Teams and now, I've reinstalled. After some trials, now I can access.

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings and run Teams in compatibility mode. See below:

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).